# Prove that the subset of a Metric space is still a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have to prove the following:

> Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space and $N \subset M$.
>    Show that $(N,d_{|N \times N})$ is still a metric space.

These are the rules I would need to show as far as i know:
$1. \; {\displaystyle d(x,y)=0\Leftrightarrow x=y}$
$2. \;  {\displaystyle d(x,y)=d(y,x)}$
$3. \;  {\displaystyle d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)}$
But in my opinion this is obvious, since if it holds for all elements of $M$ then of corse it will hold for all elements of $Y \subset X$. 
My question is what i am expected to prove here, because I am not really sure.
Thx in advance!

Comment: You are basically right: all those properties hold a fortiori.